# Integral invariant under immersion?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $n \geq m$. Is it true that for any immersion $\theta: M^m \to N^n$ and $m$-form on $N$, we have $$
\int_{M} \theta^\ast \alpha = \int_{\theta(M)} \alpha?
$$

Is is true for submersions? Or even for arbitrary smooth maps? Although very elementary, I keep confusing myself. (Do we have to argue through 'immersions are locally embeddings, use partition of unity, diffeomorphism invariance of the integral and blabla'?)

The question arose in the following setting: Take the immersion $\gamma: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ via $(x,y) \mapsto (x,xy)$, which is the figure 8. I want to show that this figure encloses a region $Z$ of oriented area 0.

So,

$$
\int_{Z} dp \wedge dq = \int_{\partial Z} p dq = \int_{\gamma(S^1)} p dq \overset{?}= \int_{S^1}\gamma^\ast(p dq) = 0, 
$$
where the last equality is an explicit computation in polar coordinates, which I omitted.

Edit: Perhaps, this is not true in general, but rather we have the special situation here, that $\gamma\vert_{S^1 - \{-1\}}$ actually has the same trace as $\gamma$. Moreover, it is injective, and thus an embedding (since $S^1$ is compact). And then, clearly, the diffeomorphism invariance kicks in. (The removal of a point does not matter for the integral).

With this, I shall conclude that: The above equality holds for any immersion which is an embedding away from a set of measure zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $M = N = S^1$, and $\theta : S^1 \to S^1 : u \mapsto 2u \bmod 2 \pi$. Note that $\theta$ is an immersion, as required, and a submersion as well.

Now $\theta(S^1)$ is (as a set) all of $S^1$, albeit double-covered.

If $\alpha$ is any form for which $\int_{S^1} \alpha = C \ne 0$, then
\begin{align}
\int_{M} \theta^\ast \alpha 
&= \int_{S^1} \theta^\ast \alpha \\
&= 2 \int_{S^1}  \alpha \\
&= 2C
\end{align}
while
\begin{align}
\int_{\theta(M)} \alpha 
& = \int_{S^1} \alpha \\
&= C \\
\end{align}

And because $C$ is nonzero, $C$ and $2C$ are different.

In short: your proposed equality is not true in general.

"But what if the immersion is 'nice', like a figure-8?" you might ask. What if the set of double-points in the image (perhaps "double values") has measure zero?"

In that case, you could let $B$ be the set of points $p \in M$ such that there's another point $q\in M$ with $\theta(p) = \theta(q)$, i.e., the set of "multiple points" in the domain, and let $N = M - B$. Something like Sard's theorem, I think, ensures that $B$, too, has measure zero. And then you have
\begin{align}
\int_{M} \theta^\ast \alpha 
&=  \int_{N} \theta^\ast \alpha \\
&=  \int_{\theta(N)}  \alpha  & \text{by the chain rule}\\
&=  \int_{\theta(M)}  \alpha  & \text{because $\theta(B)$ also has measure zero}.
\end{align}

I've been pretty sloppy here, but I think all the essentials are there. I suspect all the theorems you need are in Milnor's "Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint", for instance, combined with some book that talks carefully about the chain rule for $k$-forms.

Comment: Also, for closed differential forms, one can use cohomological arguments. If $f:M\to N$ is a smooth map, and we denote the pairing $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_M:H_k(M)\otimes H^k(M)\to\mathbb{R}$ (and likewise for $N$), then one has $\langle f_*[M],[\alpha]\rangle_N=\langle [M],f^*[\alpha]\rangle_M$, provided that $M$ has a fundamental class.

Comment: Right...and in my example, $f_{*}[M]$ turns out to be $2[M]$. I like that argument, because I don't have to remember whether the factor should be $2$ or $\frac{1}{2}$. :)

Comment: Two things: (1) Could you elaborate on the step with the chain rule? Is this not the simply the diffeomorphism invariance (whenever $M$ is compact)? (2) Am I understanding you correctly, that you say that Sard's theorem implies that the set of double points is a zero set?

Comment: @QuaereVerum Where can I read about this?

Comment: I *was* saying that *if* the set of double-images is small, then the set of double points in the domain must be small as well, but on reflection I'm not sure I believe that. But the other direction --- if the set of double points in the domain is a zero set, then so is the set of double-images  --- seems as if it's true (and handles the figure-8 case). Consider the function $f$ on $M \times M$ defined by $(x, y) \mapsto \|\theta(x) - \theta(y)\|^2$. The double points lie within its critical set, so the double images lie within the image of the critical set, which Sard says has measure zero.

Comment: Oh...and "diffeomorphism invariance" feels to me a lot like an application of the chain rule, but I'm not sure how you might have proved it, so I guess I can't say that they're "the same".